# Upon creating project, laragon's generated url leads to wampserver configuration page

Tags: apache, wamp, laragon

(Laragon) Project path: C:/laragon/www/larabook (Laragon) Pretty url: http://larabook.dev (http://larabook.dev)

I got this after quick create, but when I try to access the webpage larabook.dev I get the wampserver configuration page instead of the laravel default page. Does that mean that laravel didn't install correctly? I have version 2.0.4 and I just clicked menu > quick create > laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must stop Wampserver completely. It looks like you are running Laragon and Wampserver the same time and conflict happened.

Comment: ah, thanks. I clicked on service.msc and shut down both wamp processes and it finally worked.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Hong, I had the same issue and fixed it.

For those who want to know how to do it:
1.  Goto: Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Services and Identify the service that might be another instance of Apache
2. Select "Properties"
3. Select the Startup Type. Use the pulldown in the :Startup type to set the service to Manual or Disabled.